# Creating React native npm package with multiple screens

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I want to create a **npm package** for **react native**  which has 2 screens. which displays a list and clicking on each list item should display details.

I found lot of articles and videos on creating npm packages with single file but i am not able to find is it possible to create an npm package with **multiple screens and navigation within it**.